# Unknown Django (Postgis) exception in Apache errorlog with no Email report

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, postgis

I am running several Django sites using Apache + mod_wsgi. Now, I've just seen the following error in one of the Apache error logs:

```
[Mon Aug 22 16:12:01 2011] [error] Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'finishGEOS_r'" in <bound method GEOSContextHandle.__del__ of <django.contrib.gis.geos.prototypes.threadsafe.GEOSContextHandle object at 0xb9641f0c>> ignored
```

The strange thing is, that I don't get any mail error reports from Django at all concerning this exception (all the sites run with DEBUG=false and correct mail adresses in the ADMINS list).

Does anyone know what could cause this error? 
Does the trailing `>> ignored` means that the exception is ignored and the user doesn't get a HTTP 500 page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just a `logging.error` message rather than a 500

see
http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Re-Django-13843-destroy-geom-filling-up-the-apache-error-logs-tt365140.html#none

if you're on Apache the error log should tell you the http status of that request anyway, so you can see if the user got a 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory is good, if a destructor method is being invoked as a side effect of an exception, and a further exception occurs within the destructor then Python can't propagate the new one and so Python will log it itself direct to stderr. The original exception is then still the one that is raised. This is why you will not see the latter captured by Django and emailed out to ADMINS list etc.